# Read TIFF ICC profile using Twelvemonkeys ImageIO

Tags: java, javax.imageio, twelvemonkeys

I need to extract the embedded ICC profile from TIFF files. I can read the `IIOMetadata` and my IDE shows the `ifd` field containing the ICC profile (tag ID 34675). But how can I read it to a `ICC_Profile` object?

```
ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);

try {
    ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input).next();
    if (reader == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No image reader for file: " + file);
    }

    try {
        reader.setInput(input);
        IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);
        // metadata contains a field "ifd" containing the ICC profile
        // How to extract it?

    } finally {
        reader.dispose();
    }

} finally {
    input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `getProfile()` of the `ICCProfile` class.

Usage:

```
int profileId = ...; 
ICCProfile iccp = new ICCProfile(profileId, input);
ICC_Profile icc_p = iccp.getProfile();
```

In accordance to the code at [google result #1 for twelvemonkeys icc_profile](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/imageio/imageio-psd/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/plugins/psd/ICCProfile.java).

Comment: This is for PSD files and not available in TIFF package.

Comment: @Michael the code is available to copy it, for example. Indeed you now use the exact code as in the link I posted, except not using the ICCProfile Wrapper for getting the ICC_Profile.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. For this Twelvemonkeys package *imageio-metadata* is needed in version 3.4. Older version does not contain `TIFFEntry` class.

```
 /**
 * Extract ICC profile from an image file.
 *
 * @param file image file
 * @return ICC profile
 * @throws IOException on file errors
 */
protected ICC_Profile extractICCProfile(File file) throws IOException {

    ICC_Profile profile;

    try (ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file)) {
        ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input).next();
        if (reader == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No image reader for file: " + file);
        }

        try {
            reader.setInput(input);
            TIFFImageMetadata metadata = (TIFFImageMetadata) reader.getImageMetadata(0);
            TIFFEntry entry = (TIFFEntry) metadata.getTIFFField(TIFF.TAG_ICC_PROFILE);
            byte[] iccBytes = (byte[]) entry.getValue();
            profile = ICC_Profile.getInstance(iccBytes);
        } finally {
            reader.dispose();
        }
    }

    return profile;
}
```

Comment: You can probably get away with `Entry` rather than `TIFFEntry`, other than that this seems fine! It should also be possible to get the ICC profile using only the standard API, by getting the native tree  (in `"com_sun_media_imageio_plugins_tiff_image_1.0"` format), but I like the above better. :-)

Comment: Thanks for that. I also saw `TIFFDirectory` in Java 9, which seems to provide a way to extract this field. But I'm fine with this solution as I use your library for several other needs. And thanks for your great library :-)